# Fetching values from dictionaries nested in a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm pulling data out from the facebook API, what it returns is essentially a nested JSON looking file.

I've piped the data into the a pandas dataframe and one of the columns has returned a series of dictionaries nested in a list. (see examples in the code below).

How on Earth do I extract the values from each variable (i.e. a, b, c) when the action_type = landing_page_view?

i.e. in variable a, how do I extract the value when searching for specific action types?

i.e. return 44, 96 and 116 when I want to search the variables for 'landing_page_view'?

I've tried various for loops and things of that nature but I am not having any luck. I'm at a loss...

```
a = [{'action_type': 'landing_page_view', 'value': '44'}, {'action_type': 'link_click', 'value': '102'}, {'action_type': 'post_reaction', 'value': '5'}, {'action_type': 'post_engagement', 'value': '107'}, {'action_type': 'page_engagement', 'value': '107'}]

b = [{'action_type': 'comment', 'value': '1'}, {'action_type': 'landing_page_view', 'value': '96'}, {'action_type': 'link_click', 'value': '285'}, {'action_type': 'post_reaction', 'value': '25'}, {'action_type': 'post_engagement', 'value': '311'}, {'action_type': 'page_engagement', 'value': '311'}]

c = [{'action_type': 'post_reaction', 'value': '11'}, {'action_type': 'landing_page_view', 'value': '116'}, {'action_type': 'link_click', 'value': '319'}, {'action_type': 'post_engagement', 'value': '330'}, {'action_type': 'page_engagement', 'value': '330'}]
```

Comment: please, show your best attempt of code and the exact problem you cannot solve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for item in a:
    if item['action_type'] == 'landing_page_view':
        print(item['value'])
```

Repeat for `b` and `c`.

Answer (score 0):

You can access it like you would normally but with the list and position in the begining

example:

```
lists = [{'hello':'world', 'bye':'world'}]
print (lists[0]['hello'])
lists[0]['hello'] = "user"
print (lists[0]['hello'])
```

output:

```
world
user
```

Answer (score 0):

A one-liner solution :

```
[item['value'] for item in a if item['action_type'] == 'landing_page_view']
```

Comment: LOVE THIS! Thank you! Definitely will keep this in mind

Comment: You're welcome ! Don't forget to upvote and mark your question as answered ;)

Answer (score 0):

I feel like Jonathan's approach is best for this!

[item['value'] for item in a if item['action_type'] == 'landing_page_view']

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way of doing it for those who don't like list comprehensions so much:

```
from cherrypicker import CherryPicker
picker = CherryPicker(a)
picker(action_type='landing_page_view')['value'].get()
```

Install `cherrypicker` with `pip install --user cherrypicker`. Read about more advanced usage in the docs: https://cherrypicker.readthedocs.io.